# Want to use Navigation API in a progressive web app and want to add custom voice messages

Tags: navigation, progressive-web-apps, direction

We want to develop a PWA in which we will integrate google navigation API. We want help regarding:
1) Can we integrate navigation/directions API in PWA?
2) Can we add custom voice messages whenever a user fails to follow the direction given by Google map? For eg: If map says "take left after 200 mts" but the user takes right turn, then there should be a voice message popped up.

Please suggest.
TIA.
Mamta

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Allow me a suggestion: It is always advisable to add some code to show what you already have and to help the community help you.

Comment: Hi, we are yet to start the application. I need some basic inputs before actually starting the work.